# OOP implementation doubts

Tags: php, oop

I was starting a project today and after designing the database structure and how the data would be stored etc, I started the implementation. I am doing this on php, but the language isn't really relevant here, since my doubts are more architectured related or I guess, since I'm struggling more than I thought by implenting stuff in OOP on PHP. (Recently jumped on php, I've been coding in c++ and java before).

So, I started by creating my "User" class, simple as that, few attributes, and __construct, insert, update and delete methods. Those last 3, queries to the db.

Then this doubt came to my head, and I probably know the answer myself but I just don't find out.

I can now create instances and create new Users: `$user = new User("John", 34)` but, what if I want to edit the user "Dave"? Or I want to show all users. That method, for example, `getAllUsers()` which would return all users where would be implemented? Because it doesn't really belong to the class User does it? If it did, then how I would instance that method if I don't have any User instance?

I guess, I would need a class Users, or UserCollection which would be a collection of all the users, with the methods ´getCertainUser(id)´ and ´getAllUsers()´ which would return certain User or All of them, now then I would have a User I would be able to edit, right?

That being said, my questions is, how this problem should be addressed as the way to go, Am I complicating things too much? How this should be solved 'the correct way' in OOP. The times I've handled similar problems I've never used a database, so having a collection of users was the only way to store them, but having the database which stores the users feels redundant to have that collection of users.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You could create a `UserRepository` class which handles getting users from and saving users to the database.  There's no rule on OO that says all functionality should be on the same object.  (In fact, there's a whole lot that says it shouldn't be.)

Comment: I think this is better suited for programmers.stackexchange.com

Comment: You could make getAllUsers() and other methods not specific to a particular instance of user as `static` methods...you should know this already from Java if you did OOP in Java.

Comment: @developerwjk I've done OOP in both Java and C++, but I've never worked with a database to store the data, so to store the data I typically used a a class which would be a collection of that class, which would add, remove and return from a Map/Set or whatever the structure. Then that would write info in files and read from them if that were the case.

Now, it's a different story, since I'm working with a database, and I'm figuring out how I would handle this problem, I feel that having a class like that would be redundant.

Answer (score 1):

First, you are doing the right thing, by challenging yourself.

Obviously, there are many ways of doing things.

I highly believe that trying to keep concerns separated as much as possible and keeping classes small and simple are always two good guidelines when you want to write code that is easy to maintain and to test.

This would be one way of doing it :

To handle Models & Structures

```
Entity/User (Define the properties of a user)
Collection/User (implements ArrayIterator, just a structure)
```

To handle communication with your repository (db).

```
Repository/Mysql/User (implements getAllUsers, saveUser, deleteUser, etc.)
```

Those classes should implements common interfaces or inherit common abstract classes (if they share common logic).

For the basic persistency operation (update, delete, create), I have a little preference of moving them in the repository class instead of the entity. I prefer to avoid using "smart" entity objects. In my mind, it makes more sense. But, there are plenty of people who would disagree (and there is really no right or wrong here).

Comment: Classic ActiveRecord pattern vs datamapper

Answer (score 0):

I have a Data Model structure similar to yours, where classes represent their table counterparts. In the case of retrieving multiple of a "User" or "Categories", etc, I have a static method inside the class, that returns instances of the class. In example:

```
class User{
    public static function fetchUsersForBusiness(Business $business){
        //fetch code here into variable $users from database...
        $userObjs = [];
        foreach($users as $userData){
            $userObjs[] = new User($userData);
        }
        return $userObjs;
    }
}

class Business{

}
```

The following code would return all the users that fit a certain criteria (in this case, a business they're associated with). I then return them as the objects themselves.

I've found this model to be fairly successful, and have used it in a multitude of languages including Java, PHP, and Swift. Hope it helps you.